# Google PageSpeed abgc div id

Tags: html, validation, pagespeed

I trying to pass Google PageSpeed Insights validation, but I have 1 issue, in User Experience section:

**The tap target `<div id="abgc"></div>` is close to 1 other tap targets.**

I searched my whole page, but I cannot find this code.
Finaly I realise that id abgc is google ad sense div class for arrow in top right box on ad. But maybe I'm wrong?

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to fix this - PSI oddly enough also counts Adsense and Analytics code as issues under "Leverage browser caching", "Minify JavaScript" and a couple others as well. Their code isn't cached or minified from their side unfortunately, and the CSS they use for some formats of their Adsense ads do create tap target niggles.

The end result is that getting 100/100 when you're using Adsense or Analytics is - for all intents and purposes - impossible until the wizards at Google exclude their own code from the criteria.